# "Recursive With" PL/SQL code gives ORA-06502 error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Background

I use Oracle 12c.  My PL/SQL procedure uses a cursor containing a "Recursive With" SQL statement that selects from a materialized view that in turn does a join on a table called client_client_relationship and a view called  vw_all_clients.
The purpose of the cursor is to take an ID for a business (business_client_id) and to return the entire ownership hierarchy for that business, e.g., for business with ID 27, show what business owns it, and then what business owns that business, until finally we reach the persons who own the top-level business.
Note that the cursor uses "path" to return the full hierarchy of ownership, e.g.,  ABC Corp\DEF Corp\GHI Corp\JKL Corp\John Smith

The problem

This procedure works for many input values (business_client_id's), but for one it does not.
When the cursor-for loop that selects from this cursor for a specific business_client_id input fetches the 6th row, I get a "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" error message.

What I tried:

1. Reviewed documentation about this recursive functionality.
2. Searched for cases where this occurred to somebody else and did not find any.
3. When I removed the "path" from the SQL statement, the error did not occur, which indicates that this problem is probably caused by the value for the "path" getting too long.
   Unfortunately, I can not show the results of the procedure because the client names used are confidential.  But I can state that the 6th row returned by the cursor had a path that got significantly larger than the path for the first 5 rows (~ 120 characters), which is evidence in favor of my suspicions about the path length being the cause of this problem.

Question

What can I do to resolve this?   If my guess is correct, can I change how long the value for "path" can be?  The path can get quite long and there's nothing I can do about that fact.

If there's any other information you need, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.
Thanks.

Here is the cursor from this procedure:

```
   -- Create a cursor that recursively selects the owners of the passed client_id.  
    CURSOR c_vp_owners
    IS 
    WITH base_query (client_id2,  owner_name,  client_id1,  business_name,  client_type,  path,  Levl)       -- The aliases for the returned columns.  
    AS 
    (
     -- Select the root row -- the owner of the passed business.  
     SELECT 
        client_id2,  owner_name,
        client_id1,  business_name,   
        client_type, owner_name,
        1 Levl                                       -- The recursive level.  
    FROM client.mv_client_business_owner_tree        -- This mv joins ccr and vw_all_clients.  
    WHERE client_id1 = p_business_client_id          -- the client_id of the business -- passed in.      ******
    UNION ALL 
    -- ************************************
    -- Select the recursive rows -- if the owner returned above is a business, select its owner/s.  
    SELECT 
        mv.client_id2,   mv.owner_name, 
        mv.client_id1,   mv.business_name, 
        mv.client_type,  bq.path  ||  '/'  ||  mv.owner_name, 
        Levl + 1 
    FROM client.mv_client_business_owner_tree mv,  base_query bq
    WHERE mv.client_id1 = bq.client_id2              -- The recursive clause.  
    ) 
    SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY business_name SET row_sequence      -- Traverse the tree down the child rows first, before selecting rows that are at the same level.   
    SELECT client_id2, owner_name, client_id1, business_name, client_type, path, Levl, row_sequence
    FROM base_query;
```

A few explanatory comments about table client_client_relationship
It contains client_id1,  client_id2,  client_id1_relation,  client_id2_relation, etc.
So an example row would be:

client_id1 -- 100

client_id2 -- 200

client_id1_relation -- OWNER

client_id2_relation -- BUSINESS

Note that the OWNER could itself be a business, which would have another row in the table in which it would be the BUSINESS and another client would be the OWNER, i.e., there is a recursive relationship in this table.
The top-level row would have a person's client_id as the owner of a business.

The procedure that this cursor is in has this Declaration section:

```
    -- Declare a variable for exception handling. 
    v_client_id2    client.client.client_id%TYPE;
```

And this executable section:

BEGIN

```
 -- Open the c_vp_owners cursor and populate vessel_permit_owner with the owners of the passed vessel permit.  
 FOR vp_owners_record IN c_vp_owners LOOP 
     -- Populate a variable for exception handling.  
     v_client_id2 := vp_owners_record.client_id2; 
   
     INSERT INTO scoq_priv_owner 
             (priv_id,           program,           business_owner_client_id,           person_owner_client_id,             person_owner)
     VALUES  (p_priv_id,         p_program,         p_business_client_id,               vp_owners_record.client_id2,        vp_owners_record.path);  

 END LOOP;

 COMMIT;
```

END pr_load_scoq_priv_owners;

scoq_priv_owner.person_owner is typed as VARCHAR2(2000) -- plenty of room.

Also,
When I run just the recursive query all by itself in a script, I get the full set of 12 rows with the paths -- no errors.  The longest path is 202 characters long.

Thanks to everybody who feels like lending a hand with this.

Comment: If the problem was in the CTE you'd get "ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long" (which would be easy to fix). The PL/SQL error you are getting suggests the problem is with how you're handling the path value when it is fetched into a variable. Please edit you question to include how you use the cursor (for loop, or open+fetch), and the declaration of relevant variables. You probably just have a PL/SQL `path` variable that you fetch into which is too small.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the `SELECT` statement by itself (the recursive query), as a stand-alone SQL statement, outside of the PL/SQL context? If it runs OK, then you will know for sure that Alex Poole is right (see previous comment). In any case, if the length of `path` was the issue, you could cure it by wrapping `owner_name` (given as initial value to `path`, in the anchor member of the recursive CTE) within `to_clob(....)`.

Comment: Alex:  Sorry for the delay -- I had other pressing issues recently.   I just posted the declaration and executable sections.   As you can see there, I am not using a variable to hold the path.

Comment: Alex:   Just tried it with a VARCHAR2(2000) variable in the INSERT statement instead of using  "vp_owners_record.path" and got the same error message.

Comment: Mathguy:  I just answered that in my latest Answer below.  But I'm not sure that that proves that Alex is right -- see my last comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't post information as an "answer". Instead, edit your question.

Comment: Thanks trincot.  This is actually my first question on this web site.  I will add the info to my question.